# How to solve Internal Server Error in Next.Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I just created a next app using `npx create-next-app`. Then I installed sass by `yarn add sass`. I didn't do anything else, just type `yarn dev`... then boom. A ton of error showing in my terminal and in the browser (localhost) it says

> Internal Server Error

My terminal now looks like this

```
PS D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia> npm run dev

> booksbia@0.1.0 dev D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warn  - D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireDefault.js
    Used by 4 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js 
* D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireDefault.js
    Used by 10 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\next-dev.js

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireWildcard.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js 
* D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireWildcard.js
    Used by 6 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\next-dev.js

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\typeof.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\possibleConstructorReturn.js
* D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\typeof.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireWildcard.js

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/client/normalize-trailing-slash.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\normalize-trailing-slash.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\normalize-trailing-slash.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/client/request-idle-callback.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\request-idle-callback.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\route-loader.js
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\request-idle-callback.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\route-loader.js

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/client/route-loader.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\route-loader.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\route-loader.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/client/router.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js   
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    multi next-client-pages-loader?page=%2F_app&absolutePagePath=private-next-pages%2F_app.js! D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js   
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js  

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/client/with-router.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\with-router.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js 
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\with-router.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js 

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/head-manager-context.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\head-manager-context.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\head.js
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\head-manager-context.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js  

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/i18n/normalize-locale-path.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\i18n\normalize-locale-path.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\i18n\normalize-locale-path.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/mitt.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\mitt.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\mitt.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js  

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/router-context.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router-context.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js 
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router-context.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js  

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/router/router.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js 
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js
    Used by 4 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js  

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/router/utils/format-url.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\utils\format-url.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\utils.js


D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/utils.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/react-is/cjs/react-is.development.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react-is\cjs\react-is.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react-is\index.js
* D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react-is\cjs\react-is.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react-is\index.js

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/react-is/index.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react-is\index.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\next-server\lib\router\router.js
* D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react-is\index.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js  

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react\index.js
* D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react\index.js

D:/Web Development/BooksBia Website/Booksbia-next/booksbia/node_modules/react/index.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react\index.js
    Used by 9 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js 
* D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\react\index.js
    Used by 26 module(s), i. e.
    D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia\node_modules\next\dist\client\index.js  
info  - ready on http://localhost:3000
```

note: I tried uninstalling sass `yarn remove sass`, But the same problem remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error isn't related to Next.js itself, it looks like there's a mismatch with the path you're using in the terminal and the actual path within the file system.

In your terminal:

```
D:\Web development\Booksbia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia
       ^
```

Actual path:

```
D:\Web Development\BooksBia Website\Booksbia-next\booksbia
       ^
```

Make sure your path in the terminal matches the casing in the actual path.