# There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing, happening with every project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I went through stackoverflow.com questions, they said that you have a file `Name.js` and you are importing it like `import name from "name.js"` then it'll throw this error.

But, in my case, every single `ReactJs` and `NextJs` project is facing the same warning. Reactjs projects are running with the warning but the Nextjs project is not running`(server error)`.

some warnings

```js
./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js        
There are multiple modules with names that only 
differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.   
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\vyorius\MerchantFrontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Rahul kumar\Desktop\Projects\vyorius\MerchantFrontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\vyorius\MerchantFrontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Rahul kumar\Desktop\Projects\vyorius\MerchantFrontend\node_modules\moment\moment.js
* C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\vyorius\MerchantFrontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\vyorius\MerchantFrontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\module.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\vyorius\MerchantFrontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Rahul kumar\desktop\Projects\vyorius\MerchantFrontend\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [How to solve Internal Server Error in Next.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66143368/1870780)? In your case the mismatch is in `\Desktop`  -> `\desktop`.

Comment: @juliomalves i'm using windows 10, how can i make sure that path should be the same.

Comment: Also, the same project was working in the same directory few days ago.

Comment: Make sure you type the right path for the directory in your terminal.

Comment: @juliomalves all paths are relative, they are not absolute path.